# usage of AutoComplete feature in modern GUIs

Tags: autocomplete, usability, jquery-autocomplete

I am usual software developer (not Usability specialist); so it is interesting for me to know opinion of usability professionals about the following question. 
I would like to know: how often usability specialists recommend using feature AutoComplete (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete) in modern GUIs? Has presence of the AutoComplete in GUI become a 'standard' to the moment?

Comment: better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com imho

Comment: @ChristopheD probably better for ux.SE.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl: that seems like a good fit, yes (hadn't seen that one yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on the overall design. Autocomplete increases usability only in some cases, in other it may be inappropriate or distracting. The only way to know in your particular case is to conduct usability testing.

Comment: yes, i understand. this is why i wanted to see some 'guidelines' or articles like Microsoft's Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines document. It contains several guidelines like the following: "Editable drop-down lists....Is the drop-down list being used to list previous user input? Unless users need to review the complete list of previous input, use a text box with the auto-complete option instead."  So, can someone give memore references on documents like this one?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented **autocomplete** on several different projects with user base ranging from 200 to 500 and have collected feedback on this feature.  From my experience, users **love** it as long as it's **fast**.

My favorite control to do autocomplete is jQuery's: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

It doesn't start filtering until shortly after the user is done typing.  This is important because you don't want to flood the server w/ **too many ajax requests**.

- With Microsoft SharePoint 2007 I replaced the out-of-the-box search with a live search that does autocomplete.  This is probably the most used feature in the site
- I created a few "portlets" with large amounts of grid data and I use a built in quick find that filters the data for the user.  These are also used quite a bit

One other thing to mention is I'm not too certain how **508 compliant** it is so you may want to provide an alternative so the page w/ autocomplete can **fail gracefully** without sacraficing the user experience

Comment: "how 508 compliant" - what does it mean, the '508 compliant'?

Comment: Section 508 is an amendment to the Rehabilitation Act of 1973 which requires federal agencies to make their applications accessible to people with disabilities.  When an application meets these guidelines it is said to be "508 compliant" however, these guidelines are on different levels.  There are also a more general set of standards I follow. Google "WCAG".  That is all off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Look at discussion on http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=79272&type=member&item=49087267&qid=3ed96f17-25c4-4cac-b92d-69c37925f5bc&goback=%2Egna_79272; it is devoted to the Auto-Complete feature too. Some exampkles and ideas were written there.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.