# AutoComplete – looking for a combobox with extended functionality

Tags: .net, winforms

The standard .Net control System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox has AutoComplete functionality. Does someone know a comboxbox with LARGER functionality of AutoComplete?  For example: usage NOT PREFIX ONLY during the matching? In other words: if the list of possible values contains string ‘ABCDEFG’ and user has typed ‘BCD’ – to show the ‘ABCDEFG’ in drop-down list. There are variants possible: ‘prefix matching’ can be considered ad ‘more relevant and having higher rank’ than other matching types; etc.

Or some else AutoComplete improvements?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524596/usage-of-autocomplete-feature-in-modern-guis/5712455#5712455

Answer (score 1):

[This is extended version of textbox with auto complete.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I have seen a  lot of autocomplete controls on the http://www.codeproject.com/; but most of them were trivial ones with the ‘a string should start with entered text’ principle.

This one is more sophisticated. ... But nNo ‘ranking’ is used if several entries are matched to given <entered text>. Only ‘prefix matching’ (’starts with’) is used

Comment: I think you can modify AutoCompleteTextBox.cs class in UpdateList and FilterList functions, In these functions you can change it StartsWith to Contains in string comparision